# why cout &char operation same expresion not return the same answer

Tags: c++, cout, operation

1. 

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char c = 'x';
    cout << &c << endl;
}
```

`cout << &c << endl`print 'x'

2.

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 222222;
    char c = 'x';
    cout << &c << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

`cout << &c << endl;`print 'xd',seems the adress of the variable

os version

> Linux vm 5.19.0-45-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 09:08:58 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc version

> gcc version 12.2.0 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1)

the expression are the same ,why cout different?

Comment: The behavior is undefined. `char` pointers given to `cout` must point to null-terminated strings, yours aren't.

Comment: To print the address, add a cast to `void*`: `cout << static_cast<void*>(&c) << endl;`. Otherwise the cast from `char*` to `char const*` for the second operand of the `<<` operator is the better match during overload resulution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading out of bounds of `c` and therefore your program's behavior is undefined.

When a `char*` is passed to `std::cout`'s `<<` operator, it treats that pointer as a c-style nul-terminated string.  That means it will keep reading characters from successive bytes starting at the byte pointed to by the pointer until it finds a nul (0) byte.

But a single `char` isn't nul-terminated, so `cout` will try to read data from after the `char` object, resulting in undefined behavior.  In practice it will end up wandering into the bytes that represent the `int` `222222` and interpreting them as characters.  Eventually it will find a nul byte and stop (hopefully before it wanders out of your process's currently mapped address space and crashes).

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this

```cpp
char c = 'x';
cout << &c << endl;
```

is that, since `&c` is a `char*`, it will use this [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char, Traits>&
    operator<<( basic_ostream<char, Traits>& os, const char* s );
```

That function will use [`std::char_traits<char>::length(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(s))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) to figure out how many characters to insert into the stream. That function in turn

- return the length of the character sequence pointed to by `s`, that is, the position of **the terminating null character**.

Since you only have a single `char` (which is not `\0`), the `length` function will read whatever lies after `x` in memory. This has undefined behavior, so it could crash or find a `\0` somewhere and insert a lot of garbage into the stream.

If you want to print its address, cast to a `void*`:

```cpp
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&c) << '\n';
```